# PyArrow 3.0.0 (and >= 1.0.0): reading a parquet file fails when passing the containing directory as path

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

Fwiw, I am working in a notebook inside Azure Databricks (so "spark" is readily available in the code example below).

I have upgraded PyArrow from 0.15.1 to 3.0.0, and now it seems that I cannot read a parquet file contained in a directory by just passing the path to the directory anymore.

The error I get is

> OSError: Cannot open for reading: path '/dbfs/mnt-to-datalake/path/dir' is a directory

Note that I have a single parquet file inside the directory (not sure if that's a buggy corner-case).

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd

# this works:
dataset = pq.ParquetDataset("/dbfs/mnt-to-datalake/path/dir")
dataframe = dataset.read().to_pandas()

# this works:
table = pq.read_table("/dbfs/mnt-to-datalake/path/dir/part-00000-68f0dead-af34-495a-93f8-b5817a471c47-c000.gz.parquet")

# this works:
sparkdf = spark.read.parquet("/dbfs/mnt-to-datalake/path/dir")

# this doesn't work:
table = pq.read_table("/dbfs/mnt-to-datalake/path/dir")

# this doesn't either:
dataframe = pd.read_parquet("/dbfs/mnt-to-datalake/path/dir", engine="pyarrow")
```

My question is whether I am doing something wrong or maybe missing some configuration / options or is this expected with PyArrow 3.0.0?

Comment: It looks like the data set implementation have changed in 1.0.0. You could try adding `use_legacy_dataset =True` as an argument to `read_table` See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html

Comment: Are you able to run `import pyarrow.dataset as ds`?  It appears the behavior differs based on whether the dataset module is present or not.

Comment: `import pyarrow.dataset as ds` throws an 
ImportError: /.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow_dataset.so.300: undefined symbol

Comment: `use_legacy_dataset=True` does make it work

Comment: @RolandASc can you report an issue about this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARROW/issues/

Comment: @RolandASc How did you install pyarrow?  Did you build it from source?  Install it using `conda`?  Or install it using pip?

Comment: @RolandASc it seems you have installed pyarrow from the conda defaults channel. There are currently some issues with those packages, so please try to re-install pyarrow from conda-forge (`conda install pyarrow --channel conda-forge`)

Comment: @joris ok, thanks for the hints, I‘ll give that a try later today (won’t get to it immediately)

Comment: Reported this issue in https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/pyarrow-feedstock/issues/2 to Anaconda